# Tool Tip Show with 2 second delay when cursor came over textbox

Tags: c#, .net, windows, forms, tooltip

I'm trying to show tooltip message after 2 seconds delay not at time when mouse came over it. 
When mouse hold there for 2 seconds then tooltip appear.

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

```
toolTip.InitialDelay = 2000;
    toolTip.SetToolTip(dataGridView1, "Your tooltip is 2000 milliseconds delayed");
```

Answer (score 0):

> InitialDelay sets the period of time the ToolTip remains visible if
>   the pointer is stationary on a control with specified ToolTip text.

```
toolTip.InitialDelay = 2000;
```

> If you want to have a
>   consistent delay pattern for your ToolTip windows, you can set the
>   `AutomaticDelay` property. The `AutomaticDelay` property sets the
>   `AutoPopDelay`, `ReshowDelay`, and `InitialDelay` properties to initial
>   values based on a single time value. Every time the `AutomaticDelay`
>   property is set, the `InitialDelay` property is set to the same value as
>   the `AutomaticDelay` property. Once the `AutomaticDelay` property is set,
>   you can independently set the `InitialDelay` property, overriding the
>   default value.

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.initialdelay(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

add this on hover event for example

```
 private void button1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            toolTip1.AutoPopDelay = 10000;
            toolTip1.Show("Click 'LIVE ...", this.button1, 10000);
        }
```